# C# Mysql and multiple threads?

Tags: c#

I am hosting a WCF service which uses the mysql connector. For some reason once every 5-10 minutes I get an error that mysql is already in use. What should I do? Set it up so that it blocks, have it create a new connection per thread or setup a manager which creates a set number of connections and will block until a connection becomes available. Actually do the asynchronous calls already do that last part? Lastly whats the best way to block until another thread completes and get information from that thread?

```
public static int Query(this IDbConnection olddb, string query, params object[] args)
{
    using (var db = olddb.CloneEx())
    {
        db.Open();
        using (var com = db.CreateCommand())
        {
            com.CommandText = query;
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                com.AddParameter("@" + i, args[i]);

            return com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.EnlistTransaction (System.Transactions.Transaction transaction) [0x00000] in :0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in :0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everytime you need to query your SQL server simply:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("Some connection string"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT foo FROM bar";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // process the results
        } 
    }
}
```

This ensures that connections are returned into the connection pool that ADO.NET manages for you and so that you don't get any risks of creating multiple connections that could slow things up. Also this code is perfectly reentrant and thus by definition thread safe => it could be executed concurrently from as many threads as you wish.

Comment: I don't think creating a connection for ever query is a good idea.

Comment: @High, this doesn't create a connection for every request. It draws one from the connection pool that ADO.NET manages for you. And at the end of the using statement this connection is simply returned to the connection pool so that it can be reused. In terms of performance that will be the fastest possible way. Read the following topic for more information about connection pooling: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html

Comment: Ah, thank you for the information. Had no idea the connector worked that way.

Comment: @High, yes it works that way. SQL Server also works that way. In fact when you run the application for the first time ADO.NET creates multiple connections to the database and stores them inside a connection pool (this pool is per connection string per application domain). So when you write `conn.Open()` you are not opening a new connection you are taking one that already exists from the pool and at the end of the using statement the connection is returned to the pool. It's very efficient.

Comment: Hey it seems that it throws an exception when I try to open 2 at once. Adding the code/exception above.